# How to add a navigation bar to a viewController presented using modalView in iPad

Tags: facebook, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I am implementing a facebook integration in my ipad app.I am presenting a veiwController to load facebook URL modally using **modalPresentationStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve**. Now I want to implement a navigation bar on the top which will show a title Facebook and a button to close this view.
I tried adding a navigation bar but it didn't show up because my viewController is not tied to any navigationController and tried toolbar as a subview to the viewController's view but it shows up only after the webView is finished loading.
I want to know how should I implement a permanent navigation bar so that I can any time close the modal view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the navigation bar doesn't show up automatically, you can always add the navigation bar via IB. I was able to get it working in a [`sample project`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/ModalPresentation.zip). You can take a look and see if it helps you.

Another thing is that you are doing `modalPresentationStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;`. This is incorrect in that you are assigning a transition style to the presentation style property but works because the values are basically `enum`s and `UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve` ends up with the same value as `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`.

Comment: Thanks Deepak.That was quite helpful.Also rather than going by IB way, I created a navigation controller programmatically and set its viewController to my current one.This worked as well.And I know it was quite a long path, but I used the delegate pattern to dismiss the modalView as mentioned [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/5/3/ipad-modal-view-controllers.html).